# Implementing a very small HTTP server in c/c++ and want to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, c++, c, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to have a dynamic webpage that automaticly updates some information, this information should be received from my c/c++ application using HTTP. I have set up a socket and can send HTML and Javascript files to the browser.

I don't know how to move on. How to encapsulate my data into XMLHttpRequest objects? Or maybe this isn't the way to go? The problem is that my c/c++ application will be run on an embedded system that can't really support php or something like that.
I can't really understand how XMLHttpRequest works, I only find a lot of client examples on the web and not much about how a server should handle it.

Comment: Ummm. You really don't understand how XMLHttpRequest works. It's a client-side thing, a Javascript interface in the browser for making HTTP requests. HTTP is a data format used between the server and client to communicate requests and responses, and it's very simple. When you navigate to a link, the browser assembles an HTTP GET and sends that off to get the page's contents, and sometimes you want data from the server without navigating to a new page, so XMLHttpRequest is just a mechanism for asking the browser to get some more data. If the server supports HTTP, that's all you need.

Comment: See , if this can help you :-
http://www.websocket.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A server should handle it as any other request. From the servers point of view, it's a normal HTTP request. Return the data that the client asks for! This is usually a HTML fragment, some XML or some JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax just send normal `HTTP GET POST ...` request, you should make sure your response header is correct, such as `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you send information to the browser? The browser is client-side. To get information, you must either query the server (which you say is written in C++). If you want your client to  receive request, you should probably emulate a server-like behavior using NodeJS.